# Retrieve output from stored procedure result in R with odbc/DBI

Tags: r, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc, r-dbi

I'm trying to call a stored procedure and retrieve the output. I'm calling SQL Server using the [DBI](http://r-dbi.github.io/DBI/)-compliant [odbc](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc) package. How can I use this package? The following code returns the number of rows affected.

```
sql     <- "EXEC schema.prc_person @name_first='bob'"
channel <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn="db-remote")
guy     <- DBI::dbExecute( channel, sql)
DBI::dbDisconnect(channel); rm(channel)
```

The stored procedure is basically a `SELECT` query, but encapsulates some calculations, which is why this isn't a straight-forward query.

```
SELECT value 
FROM schema.tbl_person
WHERE name_first=@name_first --plus some other stuff in the WHERE clause
```

For reference, these two statements do what I need (using the [RODBC](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RODBC) and [RODBCext](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RODBCext) package).  Also in the `odbc` package, I've tried `dbCallProc()`, `dbSendQuery()`, and `dbSendStatement()`.

```
channel <- RODBC::odbcConnect(dsn="db-remote")
guy     <- RODBCext::sqlExecute(channel, "EXEC schema.tbl_person @name_first='bob'", fetch=T) # Notice the 'fetch' parameter
RODBC::odbcClose(channel); rm(channel)

channel <- RODBC::odbcConnect(dsn="db-remote")
guy     <- RODBC::sqlQuery(channel, "EXEC schema.tbl_person @name_first='bob'")
RODBC::odbcClose(channel); rm(channel)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dbGetQuery`:

```
sql     <- "EXEC schema.prc_person @name_first='bob'"
channel <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn="db-remote")
guy     <- DBI::dbGetQuery(channel, sql)
DBI::dbDisconnect(channel); rm(channel)
```